# Converting if-else to try-catch within PS

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have the following PS command which is as follows:

```
    if(get-customcmdlet) {
           $var = var1
        } else {
            $var = var2
}
```

Here `get-customcmdlet` is throwing an exception.

So, I have modified the above statement as follows:

```
try {
  get-customcmdlet
  $var = var1
}
catch {
$var = var2
}
```

Please let me know if it is correct way to handle the `exception` generated from `get-customcmdlet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that `try-catch` does something different than your earlier `if-else`.

`Try-Catch` checks if a execption is thrown, while `if(get-customcmdlet)` checks if your function returns something unequal `$false` or `$null`.

Given that your function supplies something even when an exception occurs on one point, you can just combine both toghether like this:

```
try {
  if(get-customcmdlet) {
      $var = var1
  }
  else {
      $var = var2
  }
}
catch {
  $var = var2
}
```

This way `$var` equals `var2` when the function returns an exception and when it returns nothing or `$false`.